# The image cannot be post to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm a newcomer to PHP and JavaScript,and I'm also a new user on StackOverflow. I've encountered some issues while lerning.

Here's the situation: I want to create a feature that allows users to upload photos by dragging and clicking. So,I'm using jQuery and Ajax to sent the data to PHP. However,while the frontend seems to be receving something,the backend isn't receiving the data,which is preventing me from entering the conditional statements.
Could you please help me,experts?
Here's my code.

```
    function js_file_upload(file_obj){
            if(file_obj != undefined){
                var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append('input_image', file_obj);
            

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../PHP/login-signup/upload.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache:false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    success: function(response) {
                        // 檢查
                        console.log(response.status);
                        console.log(response.receivedImage);
                         // 看formdate資訊
                        let object = {};
                        form_data.forEach((val, key) => {
                            object[key] = val;
                        });
                        console.log(object);

                        if(response.status == 1){
                             let fileReader = new FileReader();
                            fileReader.onload = ()=>{
                                let fileURL = fileReader.result;
                                let imgTag = `<img src="${fileURL}">`;
                                dropArea.innerHTML = imgTag;
                            }
                            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                            alert("已上傳！");
                        }else{
                             console.log("上傳失敗！");
                            alert("上傳失敗！");
                        }
                    
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("上傳失敗：" + jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                        alert("上傳失敗：" + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
```

```
    <?php

    require '../login-signup/config.php';

    $response = array(
        'status' => 0,
        'receivedImage' => isset($_FILES['input_image']) ? $_FILES['input_image'] : null
    );

    $errorSize = false;
    $errorType = false;


    if(isset($_POST['input_image']) && isset($_FILES['input_image'])){

        $arr_file_types = ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'];
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $image_folder = "../../image/uploaded_img/".$image;
        $ImgSizeMB = 10*pow(10,6);

        if($image_size > $ImgSizeMB){
            $response["status"] = 0;
            $errorSize = true;
        }elseif(!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $arr_file_types)){
            $response["status"] = 0;
            $errorType = true;
        }else{
            if($errorSize == false && $errorType == false)
                try {

                    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users(image) VALUES (:image)";
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($insertQuery);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':image', $image);

                    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $image_folder);

                    if ($stmt->execute()) {
                        $response['status'] = 1;
                    }

                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo  "資料庫連線錯誤：" . $e->getMessage();
                }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

My idea is to use Ajax to send data to PHP,store some status information in a response array,and then use the received status for further decision-making. However,when I upload something,although it reaches the "success" part,it fails to proceed because the "status" is not equal to 1. An alert pops up saying "Upload failed."

At the very beginning of the "success" section,I used the console to check the messages.I found that "status" is 0,which I assume is the initial value of the response.Then, "receivedImage" displays the filename of the uploaded image,and when I check "formdata",it also shows the image filename. This leaves me puzzled:why does "status" remain 0 when it already knows the image filename,instead of being 1?

Here's the information I've captured from the console.

[image]

Comment: Well presumably the code failed somewhere before `$response['status'] = 1;` is used, and it never entered that block. Either it took a different path, or an error occurred. Do some [debugging](https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/) of the PHP code so you can find out where it starts to go wrong. We can't run your code, so that basic process is _your_ job, and should be done _before_ asking a question here so that you can give us some meaningful information about your issue.

Comment: At a guess, maybe `if(isset($_POST['input_image'])` returns false, because there's no "input_image" POST field? There's only a FILES field with that name

Comment: `,the backend isn't receiving the data`... no that's not correct. your console response data makes clear that PHP receives the data successfully, without errors. The problem comes after that.

Comment: You're using `$_FILES['input_image']` but `$_FILES['image']` later in your code - make sure to use the correct file input name. Maybe also post your form

Comment: @brombeer you're right about the input misnomer later in the code, but I think the console data gives us enough info that we don't need to see the form, it's clear that a file is being uploaded from the client side to PHP.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your response. Regarding your observation about `isset($_POST['input_image'])` ,I made this adjustment:

```'received_Post_Image' => isset($_POST['input_image']) ? $_POST['input_image'] : null```

As you suspected, it does indeed evaluate to `null`. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @brombeer I've successfully resolved the issue by making adjustments to the key name, specifically changing it to `$_FILES['input_image']`. that PHP correctly identifies and processes the uploaded file, avoiding any errors. Thank you for pointing out this crucial detail.

Comment: No problem. If you learn how to do basic debugging in php you can start to easily spot this kind of thing yourself during testing

Comment: Glad you got it working